# How to perform comparison in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have two tables in Power BI - each has the exact same columns, however, one is from the past 7 days, and the other is from the 7 days before that. I simply want to be able to compare the data week-over-week, but am struggling to get it to work.

For example, a column used is "Source." It lists the source used for each row. I tried creating a clustered column chart and putting the "Count of Source" fields from each table in "Value" and then "Source" in "Axis." When I do this, it accurately displays the columns for one table, but the other tables' values are all messed up - it just shows the sum.

See image :

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Do you have a relationship between those tables? You can only use one column on the x-axis and if you use `'2 Weeks Ago'[Source]` then it doesn't know how that's related to `'Past Week'[Source]` so it's just giving you the total count.

Comment: I would merge the tables, with a column to indicate the dataset - you can then use this column as a dimension.